# adding run time on my java program

Tags: java

i have my Java program and i would like to add code that show the run time for calculating, but i have no idea how can i do that?

Comment: I edited, assuming Java, but I may be wrong...

Comment: this one should earn a bad question badge

Comment: @stacker: It's a legitimate question, only bad grammar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Execute your code here

        long runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        System.out.println("Runtime was "+runtime+" ms");
```

More about the `System.currentTimeMillis()` function [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Measure like this:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

.... // code block you want to measure.

System.out.println("Execution took: "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is as follows:

```
public void foo() { 

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    .

    .

    .

    System.out.println("foo took " +(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)+ " ms");

    return;

}
```

Alternatively, you can use a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple and straightforward. Just use the `System.currentTimeMillis()` that will return the number of milliseconds (ticks) from the good same old date: 00.00 - 1 January 1970.

With this you can easily calculate the time used by your calculations:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

// dirty work

long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println("Operation took "+elapsed+" millisecs.");
```

In addition another method, `System.nanoTime()`is present too. This method can have a greater accuracy according to the timer resolution of your machine and it can be used in the same identical way.